# Bootstrap 4 Navbar with multiple split navs doesn't collapse

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, navbar, hamburger-menu

In this version, only the first menu item shows in the tablet menu. When I add the style display:flex; to #navbarsExampleDefault, it shows the other items, but then I am unable to collapse/hide the menu items. Adding visibility: hidden; just hides the menu items but takes up the same space. I only included one menu item to keep it short.

```
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="icon" href="#">
    <title>Home</title>
    <!--BOOTSTRAP-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:300,300i,400,400i|Roboto:300,300i,400,400i" rel="stylesheet">
```

```
            <button class="btn btn-link navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 30 30" width="30" height="30" focusable="false"><title>Menu</title><path stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M4 7h22M4 15h22M4 23h22"></path></svg>
            </button>

            <!-- SPLIT NAVBARS -->
            <div class="btn-group navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
              <button type="button" class="btn" id="button-1"><a href="csr-lfg.html">CSR at LF</a></button>
              <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" id="button-1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
              </button>
              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu Item 1</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu Item 2</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu Item 3</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu Item 4</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu Item 5</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu Item 6</a>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: I suggest you read [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

you missed the bootstrap.js and the pooper.js you can fin more information aboit dropdown (for button ) [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/)

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:300,300i,400,400i|Roboto:300,300i,400,400i" rel="stylesheet">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <!-- SPLIT NAVBARS -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
            <button type="button" class="btn" id="button-1"><a href="csr-lfg.html">CSR at LF</a></button>
            <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle dropdown-toggle-split" id="button-1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu Item 1</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu Item 2</a>
                <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu Item 3</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu Item 4</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu Item 5</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu Item 6</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        </nav>
```

Comment: Do you have any scripts loading at the end of the body to make this work?